# Handling auto-generated UUIDs in Nova

Tags: php, laravel-nova

I have a model with a UUID property, saved in a database `uuid` field. In Nova I can declare it like this:

```
Text::make('UUID');
```

That doesn't fill the field with a default value (a new, random UUID), so I add that:

```
Text::make('UUID')
    ->default(
        function () {
            return Uuid::uuid4();
        }
    )
```

That fills the field, but it's editable, which I don't want to allow, though I do want it to be shown when looking at a detail view, so I add these:

```
Text::make('UUID')
    ->default(
        function () {
            return Uuid::uuid4();
        }
    )
    ->readonly()
    ->onlyOnDetail()
```

However, this is unusable because it results in the `uuid` field being omitted from the generated insert query, and I get an SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'uuid' doesn't have a default value
(SQL: insert into `things` (`name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (Case, ?, 2021-07-23 18:07:28, 2021-07-23 18:07:28))
```

In case it was the readonly status that was causing this, I tried just hiding it with:

```
->hideWhenCreating()
->hideWhenUpdating()
```

But that suffered the same SQL issue, suggesting it's visibility, not readonly status that causes the problem.

An alternative is to use a `Hidden` field type, which the docs suggest for exactly this kind of purpose. This works a bit, allowing the dynamic default value and preventing editing, but it doesn't allow the field to be shown on any view. Configured like this, it doesn't appear at all:

```
Hidden::make('UUID')
    ->default(
        function () {
            return Uuid::uuid4();
        }
    )
    ->showOnDetail()
```

i.e. the `showOnDetail` doesn't override the hidden nature of the field.

What combination of properties should I use to have a field that is:

1. Dynamically populated with a default value
2. Not editable
3. Hidden on creation
4. Shown on detail
5. Included in database queries?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
Text::make('Uuid')->default(function ($request) {
    return Str::orderedUuid();
}),
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-ordered-uuid

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#default-values

Comment: No, that’s the same because the Laravel uuid generator is a wrapper around the same underlying library as I’m using for uuid generation. Also I don’t think the error is at that point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready solution for that, method named: "fillUsing"

Here it is

```
            Hidden::make(__('Uuid'), 'uuid')
            ->default(function ($request) {
                return Uuid::uuid4(); // put here whatever you want, fillUsing can override the value before database query run
            })
            ->fillUsing(function ($request, $model, $attribute, $requestAttribute) {
                $model->{$attribute} = Uuid::uuid4();
            })
            ->showOnCreating()
            ->sortable(),
```